# Sending metadata when gRPC connection is getting establised

Tags: java, grpc, netty, rpc, http2

I am looking for some mechanism in which I can send some metadata(key: value) when the gRPC connection is being established. That means, only once per connection.

I know how to send it per RPC but not sure how to so it per connection level.

Any help will be appreciated.

PS: I am working in Java framework.

Comment: Why? What sort of data are you trying to send?

Comment: For example, I want my server to handle connections from a certain client in a different way. That's the use case I am trying to work on.

Comment: @EricAnderson any help here please

Comment: Metadata is for an RPC and there is no connection level metadata. You may have to send a "dummy" RPC after connection establishment just to be able send your one-time metadata